# Separar valores Double en su Parte Entera & Decimal

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

se desea separar un valor Double por ejemplo 
`Double entrada = 34.567`
y procesarlo de forma que el resultado sea:

`Parte entera: 34`

`Parte decimal: 567`

pero que el valor despues de el punto decimal salga sin el 0.(numero ) simplemente el numero como si fuera entero

Comment: Puedes aclarar un poco mas tu pregunta la veo algo confusa.

Comment: para hacer parte de lo que desea se debe separar la parte entera y la decimal para ello se ah respondido en multiples ocaciones en la version Inglesa [How do I get whole and fractional parts from double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343584/how-do-i-get-whole-and-fractional-parts-from-double-in-jsp-java)
sin embargo hay detalles de consideracion a toman en cuenta (el Limite de presicion en Double o Float). 
pero antes de dar una respuesta es necesaria que la pregunta este mejor formulada. por favor revisala para poder tener la idea mas clara y poder dar mejor consejo o respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

Con el siguiente algoritmo podrás hacer eso.
Como bien sabemos, un `String` es prácticamente un array de caracteres, o array de `Char`. Por lo tanto podemos partir la cadena, u obtener varias subcadenas a partir de esta cadena.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, podemos utilizar este conocimiento para poder partir un numero flotante en su entero y decimal.
Lo que hace el método `substring` es obtener una subcadena a partir de una posición de la cadena original, y el con el método `indexOf` obtenemos ese numero, la posición en donde se encuentra un caracter dentro de la cadena.

Con estas 2 simples funciones podemos obtener la parte entera y decimal de cualquier numero flotante.

```
double dato = 34.567;

String cad = dato + "";

String entero = cad.substring(0, cad.indexOf("."));
String decimal = cad.substring(cad.indexOf(".") + 1);

System.out.println(cad);
System.out.println("Parte Entera: " + entero);
System.out.println("Parte Decimal: " + decimal);
```

Comment: @Silencio2 Con `NumberFormat` siempre se asegurara que el separador siempre sea `.`. El separador depende de la localizacion en donde se encuentre, pero esto se puede cambiar con `Locale` y `NumberFormat`. Despues se utiliza las funciones `parse` del objeto perteneciente a la clase `NumberFormat`

Comment: eso es un poco contradictorio. osea simpre es pero no siempre es? como? como es que siempre es `.` pero depende de `locale` ?  es o no es? podrias ser mas claro creo que no comprendo tu comentario

Comment: Los separadores de los decimales, así como el formato de la fecha varia dependiendo de la zona o localizacion en la que este, con Locale se puede formatear una fecha o un numero decimal para que cumpla el estandar zonal. Por ejemplo, en Donde yo vivo se maneja el formato `.` para decimales, cosa que en otros paises puede ser `,`

Comment: ok, de hecho veo que estaba incorrecto pero @ElPapu aunque sobre el camino correcto no dio la explicacion completa. 
de acuerdo a la documentacion de [Java Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-)
el separador de `toString` Simpre es `'.' ('\u002E')` puesto ya sea para bien o para mal Cuando se escribio Double se desidio el separador seria `.` es mas bien si se requiere mostrar un separador Regionalizado se debe usar `NumberFormat` (osea es alreves de como se expreso) Le agradesco @ElPapu por forzarme a aprender algo nuevo XD

Answer (score 0):

HOLA LA FORMA QUE LO HARÍA SERÍA ASÍ.... AUNQUE HAY OTRA FORMA.

```
public class Probando {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double dato = 19.3456;        //Primero creas una variable en el main con tu valor.
        System.out.println(sacarNumeroDespuesDelPunto(dato)); // y la ingresas en este método.
        // La respuesta sería 3456.
    }

    /*
     * Se muy bien lo que necesitas.
     * Te explicare.. te hice este metodo.. lo puedes...
     */
public static long sacarNumeroDespuesDelPunto(double valor){ // creamos un método que reciba un double y retorne un long.

    long respuesta = 0; // Inicializamos la variable a retornar.
    String dato = ""+ valor;  //convertimos el double en un STRING para poder trabajar con el.
    char signo= '.'; // Creamos un char con signo punto(.) que tiene un double.
    int coincidencia = dato.indexOf(signo); // Utilizamos un entero.. Aqui tomamos a dato y le ponemos un 
    // indexOf() <-- Lo que hace el.. busca la primera coincidencia en caracteres...
    // Entonces le mandamos a signo..  y nos dice en que posisción se encuentra el punto.
    // ejemplo 23.657  La posisción sería 2 porque empieza a contar desde 0 como un arreglo.
    //Recuerda que si en indexOf no encuentra nada COINCIDENCIA valdría -1.

    if(coincidencia != -1){ // Ponemos esta condicción por si coincidencia diferente a -1, osea que encontro un punto en el número
    String parte = dato.substring(coincidencia+1); // utilizamos un subString para cortar la parte. le decimos
    // Corte a dato despues del punto y deme todo lo que haya despues.. si quisieras que solo te den solo los dos decimales le
    //Pones tope ejemplo. String parte = dato.substring(coincidencia+1, 3 ); Recuerda que cuenta desde el 0.

    respuesta =Long.parseLong(parte); //por ultimo conviertes a parte en un long.
    }

    return respuesta; //Retornas la respuesta.


    }

}
```

Espero te sirva el metodo.

Comment: esta respuesta posee errores. `int respuesta` para guardar la parte entera de un `double` puede dar error puesto existe perdida de precisión por que el `integer` solo puede guardar hasta `(2^31)-1`. y `Double` puede guardar hasta `2^52` (o por ahi) la parte entera de un double se debe guardar en un `long` .

Comment: Bueno gracias por corregirme. pero creo que le sirve este metodo solo lo cambia por tipo long y listo..

Comment: Hola @yi. tienes razon. si se cambia las referencias de `int` por `long`. corrige el problema, y esperaba que se hicieran esos cambios a la respuesta. antes de hacer un comentario. pero al momento que escribo este comentario aun estan las referencias a `int`.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo corregí.. Dios te bendiga